# Full site links on mobile website

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I have asked it before, but my question was closed.

So I ask again, If Im using jquerymobile with Joomla, how can I add link to my full site version.

Tried this "?device=desktop", but it didnt work.
Does anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite relevant to jQueryMobile. You have to check configuration file of Joomla and how to close or switch off Mobile version.